# Trying to change function parameter from inside using a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, pathlib

This function checks for files in a directory, then if there is already a file with that name it appends a auto increment number such as (1),(2),etc. For some reason my self.count, self.index or self.file_name is not being update after it goes trough the loop.

```
class FileAutoinc:

    def __init__(self,file_name,file_stem,file_suffix,dst_directory):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.file_stem = file_stem
        self.file_suffix = file_suffix
        self.dst_directory = dst_directory
        self.count = 0
        self.index = f'({self.count})' 
        


    def condition_req(self):
        
        while self.file_name in os.listdir(self.dst_directory):  
            if len(self.file_stem) >=3:
                if self.file_stem[-3:] == self.index:    
                    self.count += 1
                    self.file_name = f'{self.file_stem[0:-3]}{self.index}{self.file_suffix}'
                    print(f'New file name: {self.file_name}')

                else:
                    break

            else:
                 break
```

I want the file_name to be updated if already in a directory. For example lets say I have a file called example.txt in folder A. Then if I want to move a file with the same name (example.txt) append a number to it like example(1).txt.

Comment: Changing `self.count` doesn't magically cause `self.index` to update, the only value it ever holds in this code is `"(0)"`.

Comment: Why do you need both `self.count` and `self.index`? Just use `({self.count})` when updating `self.file_name`.

Comment: Technically, you could make `self.index` a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property), that computes its value on reference.

Comment: And `self.file_stem` also seems redundant, it's always the same as `self.file_name`. Why don't you remove the last 3 characters when creating it?

Comment: okay that makes sense, but why isn't changing self.file_name?

Comment: It *is* changing it, but it's changing it to the same thing every time, so the loop never ends.

Answer (score -1):

A bit modified, the method `condition_req()` recursively do the job

```
import os
import re

class FileAutoinc:

    def __init__(self, file_name, dst_directory):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.dst_directory = dst_directory
        self.count = 1

    def condition_req(self):
        
        if self.file_name in os.listdir(self.dst_directory):
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(self.file_name)
            if re.findall(r'.*\(\d+\)$', name):
                name = name[:name.rfind('(')]
            self.file_name = f"{name}({self.count}){ext}"
            self.count += 1
            self.condition_req()
        else:
            print(f"New name is: {self.file_name}")
```